# wpf datagrid refresh without INotifiedChanges

Tags: wpf, datagrid, refresh

I've datagrid in wpf and some code in .xaml.cs

```
List<TaskHeader> taskHeaders;
//initialization of taskHeaders
taskDataGrid.ItemsSource = taskHeaders;
```

So after clicking refresh button I need to update my taskHeaders changes into taskDataGrid view, but i can't find the way without implementing ObservableCollection. `taskDataGrid.Items.Refresh();` is not working.

```
taskDataGrid.ItemsSource = null;
taskDataGrid.ItemsSource = taskHeaders;
taskDataGrid.Items.Refresh();
```

is not working too
any idea? please help

Comment: Why don't you want to use what works really well?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(taskHeaders).Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this and this works:

My XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<DockPanel>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Content="Change list and refresh grid" Click="OnRefreshButtonClicked"/>
    <DataGrid x:Name="taskDataGrid"/>
</DockPanel>
```

My code behind:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApplication
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var taskHeaders = new List<TaskHeader>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
                taskHeaders.Add(new TaskHeader() { Property = "Property " + i });

            this.taskDataGrid.ItemsSource = taskHeaders;
        }

        private void OnRefreshButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var taskHeaders = (List<TaskHeader>)this.taskDataGrid.ItemsSource;

            // Make changes on taskHeaders by removing first item.
            taskHeaders.RemoveAt(0);

            CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(taskHeaders).Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

and my dummy TaskHeader class:

```
namespace WpfApplication
{
    public class TaskHeader
    {
        public string Property { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Stipo, you choose me way to understand the button click event or other user action is necessary to get refresh on DataGrid, here is all situation description:

Comment: No problem. If you are satisfied with the answer, please accept it as the best possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of bind whole list,try this one (Actually I dont know how is your logic but may be help somebody).

taskHeader value is a one TaskHeader object.

taskDataGrid.Items.Add(taskHeader)